# You've reached the device limit. Some features will not be enabled. Android Things OTA

Tags: android-things, ota, android-things-console

I have done *Android Things* OTA  remote update 4 times and it was successfully happened. But this time it is giving error which is

> "You've reached the device limit. Some features will not be enabled"

I do not know why it is giving me this error. Due to this I am not able to do the remote update.

If anybody knows this or any idea, please share.

Answer (score 1):

[The issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162459107) has been raised at the Google's issue tracker. There was stated the following:

> You can continue to use the Android Things Console for development purposes. Functionality like OTAs will continue to work.

Answer (score 1):

The 100 device limit is noted in the Android Things [terms of service](https://developer.android.com/things/terms/console) (Section 1.1):

> Subject to the Terms, Google grants you a limited, revocable, non-transferable, non-exclusive, right to (i) access and use the Android Things Console and (ii) install the Software on up to 100 devices per product owned or controlled by you for the sole purpose of internal development and testing of devices that have integrated the Software.

I would also recommend reviewing the latest information on the [FAQ page](https://developer.android.com/things/faq) to learn more about the Android Things platform status.